# Drupal 6: Username and Password fields are missing from /user/x/edit profile page

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

This isn't the register page, but rather the edit user page.  I don't show any updates to the user module, and no hooks (that I can find) that would have removed the fields.

Also, I checked the CSS for hidden or display:none on the elements, but in fact, the form fields are not in the HTML source at all.

Comment: Upon taking a closer look at this, it looks like all the fields from the user/%/edit page are missing EXCEPT the fields for Post Categories, Forced Term Association, and Notifications

Comment: it must be some issue with the changes you did with either permissions or some other modules you installed recently.

Comment: Makes sense, Joshi.  Any ideas on the best way to trace/debug changes to that form by other modules?

Comment: First check with firebug if you get those fields but hidden by CSS. If not, try using hook_form_alter and check what you get with $form. You will need a custom module for this and set its weight in db to 0. Use 'exit;' after you print the $form.

Comment: Joshi, after a bit of coding, we were able to find the issue and resolve it, thanks to your suggestion above.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggestion from Joshi above proved to be effective.  Problem is resolved.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see where I could do that. Seems I can up vote an answer, not a comment?